# Opening a .docx file (hosted on OneDrive) with iOS Microsoft Word native app from another App

Tags: ios, swift, ms-word, ms-office, onedrive

To Open a word document(.docx) file stored on OneDrive with the native iOS MS Word app from My Native iOS App the following URL is constructed as per [MS Office Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/integrate-with-office-from-ios-applications). Code for the same is as follows:

```
@IBAction func openDocumentInWord(_ sender:UIButton) {
    //Share Via Link generated from one drive.
    //let directLinkToOneDrive = "https://1drv.ms/w/s!AgOycw0cHm8echmY8v52woUUHKE?e=oWE9wB"

    //One drive direct link obtained as mentioned here http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-get-direct-download-link-from.html
    let directLinkToOneDrive = "https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=1E6F1E1C0D73B203&resid=1E6F1E1C0D73B203%21114&authkey=AMsjQBcZS20qj2E&em=2"
    let msword = "ms-word:ofe|u|".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    guard let _URLToOpen = NSURL.init(string: ("\(msword)\(directLinkToOneDrive)")) else{
        return
    }

    //Encoded URL Generated: ms-word:ofe%7Cu%7Chttps://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=1E6F1E1C0D73B203&resid=1E6F1E1C0D73B203%21114&authkey=AMsjQBcZS20qj2E&em=2

    let canOpen = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(_URLToOpen as URL)
    if(canOpen){
        UIApplication.shared.open(_URLToOpen as URL, options: [:]) { (isSuccess) in
            print(isSuccess)
        }
    }
}
```

My App open's up the MS word Application but MS word is not able to open the file. It keep's on throwing the following error.
       [image]

**So question, is there an issue with the directLinkToOneDrive URL that I have obtained?

Is so how to get the right URL fro one-drive?**

Note: The direct link works for opening docx file in Safari.

**Edit:** Based on Leo's comment tried by saving the file to documents directory and passing the file path (below) but still getting same error.
*ms-word:ofe%7Cu%7Cfile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5DFD4606-2701-496A-9C72-3636806BEB49/Documents/Sample.docx*

Comment: Have you tried saving it locally before trying to open it?

Comment: @LeoDabus . If you mean in My-App Document's Directory, Yes I tried that option but it seems ms-word iOS only supports documents stored in SharePoint or OneDrive for opening from third-party developer app.

Comment: Try using document interaction controller

Comment: @LeoDabus That doesn't help my cause. Opening with MS Word app will help achieve editing the document.

Comment: Try renaming your file to .doc